# azure node app run openssl get error 'spawn openssl ENOENT'

Tags: node.js, azure, express, openssl

code below :

```
var out = '';
  var file = __dirname + '/../public/images/_DSC5813.jpg';
  execFile('openssl', ['sha1', file], function (err, sdtout, sdterr) {
    if (err) {
      out = err.message; // the error message is 'spawn openssl ENOENT'
      console.log(err);

    }
    else {
      out = sdtout.toString();
      console.log(sdtout);
      console.log(out);

    }
    res.render('index', { title: 'Express', message: out });
  });
```

anyone have the same issue seem to be the azure server not install openssl correctly?!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Azure Web App default environment doesn't install the openssl application. You can go to `https://<your_web_app_name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/Env.cshtml` for a glance of all the installed application / environment and path variables.

If you need to execute the openssl application in your project, you can put the executable application `openssl.exe` in your package, and deploy then together to Azure. When you need to execute in your project, you can leverage the relative path in your application's directory path.